# How can I iterate over the results of a hash map where the value is a list?

Tags: java, hashmap

I've created a hash map that groups unique keys that combine three parameters, i.e. customer, sc and admin. I want to create a unique list of keys with a list of servers attached. I've implemented the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String items = "customer1^sc1^admin1|server1~" +
                "customer1^sc1^admin1|server2~" +
                "customer1^sc1^admin1|server3~" +
                "customer2^sc1^admin1|server1~" +
                "customer3^sc1^admin1|server3~" +
                "customer3^sc1^admin1|server2~";

        // Set up raw data
        List<String> splitItems = Arrays.asList(items.split("\\s*~\\s*"));

        // Display raw data
        System.out.println("Raw List: " + items);

        // Create a hash map containing customer name as key and list of logs as value
        HashMap<String, List<String>> customerHashMap = new HashMap<>();

        // Loop through raw data
        for (String item : splitItems) {

            // Create new lists. One for customers and one for logs
            // List<String> customerList = new ArrayList<>();
            List<String> logList;

            String list[] = item.split("\\|");

            String customer = list[0];
            String log = list[1];

            logList = customerHashMap.get(customer);
            if (logList == null){
                logList = new ArrayList<>();
                customerHashMap.put(customer, logList);
            }

            logList.add(log);
            // System.out.println(logList);
        }

        // Print out of the final hash map. Customer "a" should only have "a" logs, customer "b" with "b", etc.
        System.out.println("");
        List<String> hashMapList = new ArrayList<String>();
        Iterator it = customerHashMap.entrySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) it.next();
            String output = pair.getKey() + "|" + pair.getValue().toString();
            hashMapList.add(output);
            it.remove();
        }

        String hashMapResultString = hashMapList.toString();
        String hashMapResultFormatted = hashMapResultString.replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", "");
        System.out.println(hashMapResultFormatted);

    }
```

**Raw List:** `customer1^sc1^admin1|server1~customer1^sc1^admin1|server2~customer1^sc1^admin1|server3~customer2^sc1^admin1|server1~customer3^sc1^admin1|server3~customer3^sc1^admin1|server2~`

**Hash Map String:**

```
customer2^sc1^admin1|server1, customer3^sc1^admin1|server3, server2, customer1^sc1^admin1|server1, server2, server3
```

I now want to use the hash map to create a string which will be parsed further (don't ask lol). So I set the keys and values of the hash map to a string which separates them with a unique delimiter `|`. The problem is that because the key is a `List<String>`, when printing I can't ascertain the beginning of every new `key` if its value is a list with more than one item, i.e. `customer3^sc1^admin1|server3, server2,` is followed immediately by `customer1^sc1^admin1|server1, server2, server3`. I need a delimiter here that separates them.

My ideal output would look like this:

```
customer2^sc1^admin1|server1~customer3^sc1^admin1|server3, server2~customer1^sc1^admin1|server1, server2, server3~...
```

How can I achieve this?

**Update:**

This is the answer I ultimately found useful for my particular problem:

```
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
        for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : customerHashMap.entrySet()) {
            s.append(entry.getKey() + "|");
            List<String> list = entry.getValue();
            for (String item : list) {
                if (item != list.get(list.size() - 1)) {
                    s.append(item + "^");
                } else {
                    s.append(item);
                }
            }
            s.append("~");
        }
        System.out.println(s.toString());
```

Comment: You seem to misunderstand, `HashMap<String, List<String>>` here it's the value which a List, not the key (as said in title)

Comment: Sorry. Bad typo. You''ll see that in the question itself I'm more consistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through a map's entry set:

```
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
for(Map.Entry<String,List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
   s.append(entry.getKey() + "\n");
   List<String> list = entry.getValue();
   for(String item : list) {
      s.append("   " + item + "\n");
   }
}
return s.toString();
```

For the sake of a clearer example, I've output a different format from the one you asked for, but this illustrates how to work with a map of list values. When adapting to your needs, have a look at `java.util.StringJoiner` and the related `Collectors.joining()`; it may well be useful.

---

Streams can be handy here:

```
 String encoded = map.entrySet().stream()
     .map( entry -> entry.getValue().stream()
               .collect(Collectors.joining("^"))
             + "|" + entry.getKey())
     .collect(Collectors.joining("~"));
```

What happens here is:

- We get a stream of `Entry<String,List<String>` out of the map
- The lambda `entry -> ...` converts each entry into a string of the form `val1^v2^v3^...^valN|key`, i.e. we are mapping a `Stream<Entry<>>` into a `Stream<String>`.
- the final `collect()` joins the stream of strings into a single string using `~` as a delimiter.

Comment: I think the solution here would be to remove the **next character** after the occurrence of some other character, i.e. remove the **next** ``,`` after every ``~``.

Comment: @santafebound you're talking about a general problem with regard to comma-joining lists. It's better to not add unwanted separators, than it is to add them then remove them. Take a look at the source for StringJoiner - http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/StringJoiner.java - they do it a neat way.

Comment: @santafebound but if you just want the effect, use StringJoiner instead of writing your own -- that's what it's for.

Comment: @santafebound updated with fancy-schmancy stream oriented option.

Comment: Does this this new method have an equivalent in Java 1.5?

Comment: You'd have to be nuts to use Java 5. Even Java 6 is long out of support and has know security  bugs. No, Streams are not available in 5.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful answers. Cheers :) I will probably make use of the StringBuilder approach because I'm working with an older system.